# Django Populate Dropdown with Records

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm only using forms.Form but I'm trying to show two choice fields that have selections of the associated models.

It basically needs to show the same names but in both fields. Here's what I'm using.

```
class ManagersForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = A

    leader = forms.ChoiceField()
    co-leader = forms.ChoiceField()
```

Is there not just a way that I can parse the users?

```
users = MyUser.objects.filter(a=i)
```

Comment: Is this a Form or a ModelForm? If it's the latter, look at using ```ModelChoiceField```.

Comment: I don't really mind, I just need the similar functionality to how it works in the admin interface

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ModelForm not Form, if the field from the Model is a ForeignKey the form will render the field as a dropdown of the associated model:

```
class ManagersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = A
```